# Insertion Sort with a Singly Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, insertion-sort

I'm trying to write a method for my LinkedList class that will sort a linked list of Person objects by their name. My method compiles fine but when I try to sort a list of people, the output is incorrect. It also never stops running. For example, this code

```
Person *p1 = new Person("K", "B");
Person *p2 = new Person("A", "A");
Person *p3 = new Person("S", "M");
Person *p4 = new Person("B", "M");

LinkedList ll;
ll.insertFront(*p1);
ll.insertFront(*p2);
ll.insertFront(*p3);
LinkedList newList = ll.insertionSort();
newList.print();
cout << endl;
```

Gives this output

```
B, K

A, A
```

Could anyone help me figure out where I went wrong with my algorithm? Thanks!

This is the method I use to sort names by both first and last:

```
int Person::compareName(Person p)
{
    if (lName.compare(p.lName) > 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (lName.compare(p.lName) == 0)
    {
        if (fName.compare(p.fName) > 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else return -1;
    }
    else return -1;
}
```

Insertion Sort Method:

```
LinkedList LinkedList::insertionSort()
   {
    //create the new list
    LinkedList newList;
    newList.front = front;
    
    Node *n;
    Node *current = front;
    Node *trail = NULL;
    
   for(n=front->link; n!= NULL; n = n->link)//cycle through old chain
{
    Node* newNode = n;
    
    //cycle through new, sorted chain to find insertion point
    for(current = newList.front; current != NULL; current = current->link)
    {
        //needs to go in the front
        if(current->per.compareName(n->per) < 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        
        else
        {
            trail = current;
            
        }
    }
    
    //if it needs to be added to the front of the chain
    if(current == front)
    {
        newNode->link = newList.front;
        newList.front = newNode;
    }
    //else goes in middle or at the end
    else{
        newNode->link = current;
        trail->link = newNode;
    }

    return newList;
}
```

Comment: Title tweaked; while I haven't looked at the details, I suspect this is going to be an algorithm issue rather than a language one so I'm not sure it matters *that* much.

Comment: Have you tried *debugging*? In other words, have you stepped through the code to see what it was doing?

Comment: Oh boy. When I read your code I have a temptation to just write it for you, instead of trying to understand what you are doing here. That would be much faster and easier. Your code just baked my noodle. Your `compareName` method is not correct, but it gives correct results for the provided example, so the problem is not there. Please detach an element from the old list and attach it to the new one in the right place, instead of trying to relink a list breaking links in the process. Well that's what I think you are doing, but I can't really tell for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have current->link in your inner for loop, and in the else to the inner for loop.  I assume that you really have current = current->link in the for loop or it does nothing.  If so, you'd be skipping every other element.

You also have a language thing-  you aren't creating new nodes, you're altering the nodes on your original list.  That measn you're changing the list as you walk it, which will corrupt the list as you sort it.  Behavior is undefined and dependent on the order in which you add elements.

Comment: Yeah, the second point is important. The problem is a fundamental misunderstanding of pointers, it looks a bit like it was unsuccessfully translated from Java.

Comment: That would cause a problem in Java too, since everything's a reference.  But yeah, this has the smell of homework to it so it probably the OP not understanding pointers.  Which is fine, so long as he actually asks the right followups and learns.

Comment: Yes I understand Java, and I just started taking this class in c++ so I'm still confused about the pointers.So would I have to create a new node in the outer loop so I can add it to the new LinkedList? And if I'm creating a new node with the same person object, how would I go about that? I have a copy constructor in my Node class but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: So in C++ you have objects and pointers.  Pointers are basically memory addresses-  think of RAM as a giant array.  A pointer is an index into that array.  When you do something to a pointer, you do it to the variable stored at that index in RAM.  If two classes both have a pointer to the same place, doing anything to it will change it for both classes.  That's what you're doing here-  you aren't creating new nodes, so both classes see the change.

Comment: So I would have to create new nodes for the newList and then use a desconstructor on the old list?

Comment: You wouldn't deconstruct the old list-  you'd keep it as is.  That way you have the old, unsorted list and the new sorted list, and each would have a full copy.

Comment: I edited my for loop and created a new node for each node that is being copied over. The changes are posted in the code above. Now though when I go to test it, there is no output but the program never stops running. I believe that means the loop is infinite but I'm not sure why that would happen.

Comment: You aren't creating a new node yet.  To create a pointer to a new object, you need to use the new operator.  What you're doing is creating a new pointer, but setting it equal to the value of the old one-   that sets it equal to the address of the old object.  You need to create a new object at a new location in RAM, which is what new does.

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't understand pointers all that well. I've tried searching online for tutorials and I think I am just thrown off because I have pointers to nodes which point to objects. I put this in the for loop. And it runs fine now but I still get incorrect output. `Person *p = new Person(n->per);
Node* newNode = new Node(*p);`

Answer (score 0):

Even after you have fixed any linked list handling issues (which I haven't looked at), your `compareName()` function has a flaw - when comparing `Person` objects that have the same last name it may return from the function without providing a value (in the cases where `Name.compare(p.fName) <= 0`).

Getting an indeterminate result from the compare function will break pretty much any sort.

Since this is likely homework, I'll leave correcting the problem as an exercise.

Comment: Ok so I added else return -1; for instances where fName.compare(p.fName) <= 0

Comment: @KristyB: you need to return 0 in the case where `fName.compare(p.fName) == 0`.

Comment: Ahh I see. Missed that one